# How do I replicate the Azure Resource Manager template uniquestring() function in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, templates

I have an Azure-hosted service which is automatically deployed (in our build process) using ARM templates, with multiple instances of the service in different resource groups. Several of the resources require globally unique names, and to support this I'm using the `uniquestring` function (typically against the resource group ID) to generate part of those resource names. Names follow a templated pattern, e.g. Instance Name + Component Name + Unique String = "Example.WebAPI.abcd1234efgh5"

My problem arises later when using Powershell scripts to perform maintenance on those resources - I need the resource name, which means using the same template to generate the name from the instance, component and resource group IDs. However, there is no function in Powershell that returns the same value as the ARM `uniquestring` function for the same input.

As far as I'm aware, `uniquestring` is simply generating a hash of the input string and returning it as a 13-character representation; does anyone know the specifics of this hash process so it can be duplicated in Powershell, or if it has already been done?

I've looked at the answer for [Can I call ARM template functions outside the JSON deployment template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064916/can-i-call-arm-template-functions-outside-the-json-deployment-template), but this requires the use of output parameters in the initial ARM template and assumes the value is used immediately; whereas in my use case I need the resource name some weeks or months after the initial deploy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party but below Powershell script should do the job.

This was translated from C# which has the keyword "unchecked" and therefore the functions uncheckedUInt32Multiply and uncheckedUInt32Addition is used to not cause an overflow when multiplying numbers together.

I cannot take credit for this since i just made the transition from C# to Powershell.

C# function source is from: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Deployments.Expression/

Usage:

```
# Pass an ordinary string
.\ArmUniqueStringGenerator.ps1 -InputStringValue "test example"

# Get Resource group name and pass the id to unique string generator.
(Get-AzResourceGroup -Name <Resource Group Name>).ResourceId | .\ArmUniqueStringGenerator.ps1
```

```
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$InputStringValue
    )

    #region Functions
    function GenerateUniqueString {
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$InputString,
            [uint]$seed = 0u
        )

        [uint[]] $dataArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($InputString)

        [int] $num =  $dataArray.Length
        [uint] $num2 = $seed
        [uint] $num3 =  $seed

        $index = 0

        for ($index = 0; $index + 7 -lt $num; $index += 8) {
            [uint] $num4 = [uint]($dataArray[$index] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 1] -shl 8) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 2] -shl 16) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 3] -shl 24))
            [uint] $num5 = [uint] ($dataArray[$index + 4] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 5] -shl 8) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 6] -shl 16) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 7] -shl 24))
            $num4 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num4 597399067
            $num4 = scramble -value $num4 -count 15
            $num4 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num4 2869860233u
            $num2 = $num2 -bxor $num4
            $num2 = scramble -value $num2 -count 19
            $num2 = uncheckedUInt32Addition $num2 $num3
            $num2 = uncheckedUInt32Addition (uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num2 5) 1444728091
            $num5 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num5 2869860233u
            $num5 = scramble -value $num5 -count 17
            $num5 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num5 597399067
            $num3 = $num3 -bxor $num5
            $num3 = scramble -value $num3 -count 13
            $num3 = uncheckedUInt32Addition $num3 $num2
            $num3 = uncheckedUInt32Addition (uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num3 5) 197830471

        }

        $num6 = [int]($num - $index)
        if ($num6 -gt 0) {

            $elseVal = switch($num6)
            {
                2 { 
                    [uint]($dataArray[$index] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 1] -shl 8)) 
                } 
                3 { 
                    [uint]($dataArray[$index] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 1] -shl 8) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 2] -shl 16)) 
                }
                default { 
                    $dataArray[$index] 
                }
            }
            
            $num7 = [uint](($num6 -ge 4) ? ([uint]($dataArray[$index] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 1] -shl 8) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 2] -shl 16) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 3] -shl 24))) : $elseVal)
            $num7 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num7 597399067
            $num7 = scramble -value $num7 -count 15
            $num7 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num7 2869860233u
            $num2 = $num2 -bxor $num7
            if ($num6 -gt 4)
            {
                $value = switch($num6)
                {
                    6 { 
                        uncheckedUInt32Multiply ($dataArray[$index + 4] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 5] -shl 8)) -1425107063
                    } 
                    7 { 
                        uncheckedUInt32Multiply ($dataArray[$index + 4] -bor ($dataArray[$index + 5] -shl 8) -bor ($dataArray[$index + 6] -shl 16)) -1425107063
                    } 
                    default { 
                        uncheckedUInt32Multiply ($dataArray[$index + 4]) -1425107063
                    } 
                }
                $value = scramble -value $value -count 17
                $value = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $value 597399067
                $num3  = $num3 -bxor $value
            }
        }


        $num2 = $num2 -bxor [uint]$num
        $num3 = $num3 -bxor [uint]$num
        $num2 = uncheckedUInt32Addition $num2 $num3
        $num3 = uncheckedUInt32Addition $num3 $num2
        $num2 = $num2 -bxor $num2 -shr 16
        $num2 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num2 2246822507u
        $num2 = $num2 -bxor $num2 -shr 13
        $num2 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num2 3266489909u
        $num2 = $num2 -bxor $num2 -shr 16
        $num3 = $num3 -bxor $num3 -shr 16
        $num3 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num3 2246822507u
        $num3 = $num3 -bxor $num3 -shr 13
        $num3 = uncheckedUInt32Multiply $num3 3266489909u
        $num3 = $num3 -bxor $num3 -shr 16
        $num2 = uncheckedUInt32Addition $num2 $num3
        $num3 = uncheckedUInt32Addition $num3 $num2

        $final = ([ulong]$num3 -shl 32) -bor $num2
        $uniqueString = Base32Encode $final
        return $uniqueString
    }


    $encodeLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567"

    function scramble {
        param (
            [uint] $value,
            [int] $count
        )
        return ($value -shl $count) -bor ($value -shr 32 - $count)
    }


    function Base32Encode {
        param (
            [ulong] $longVal
        )
        $strOutput = ""
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt 13; $i++) {
            $charIdx = [int]($longVal -shr 59)
            $charAddition = $encodeLetters[$charIdx]
            $strOutput = $strOutput + $charAddition
            $longVal = $longVal -shl 5;

        }
        return $strOutput
    }

    function Base32Decode {
        param (
            [string] $encodedString
        )
        $bigInteger = [Numerics.BigInteger]::Zero
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $encodedString.Length; $i++) {
            $char = $encodedString[$i]
            $ltrIdx = $encodeLetters.IndexOf($char)
            $bigInteger = ($bigInteger -shl 5) -bor $ltrIdx
        }

        return $bigInteger / 2
    }

    function uncheckedUInt32Multiply {
        param (
            [long] $nbrOne,
            [long] $nbrTwo
        )

        $nbrOnePos = $nbrOne -lt 0 ? [uint]::MaxValue - (-$nbrOne) + 1 : $nbrOne
        $nbrTwoPos = $nbrTwo -lt 0 ? [uint]::MaxValue - (-$nbrTwo) + 1 : $nbrTwo

        $uintMaxVal = [uint]::MaxValue

        $longMultiplyResult = ([ulong]$nbrOnePos * [ulong]$nbrTwoPos)

        $remainder = $longMultiplyResult % $uintMaxVal
        $totalDevisions = ($longMultiplyResult - $remainder) / $uintMaxVal

        $result = $remainder - $totalDevisions
        
        if ($result -lt 0) {
            return ($uintMaxVal - (-$result)) + 1
        }
        return $result
    }

    function uncheckedUInt32Addition {
        param (
            [uint] $nbrOne,
            [uint] $nbrTwo
        )

        $nbrOnePos = $nbrOne -lt 0 ? [uint]::MaxValue - (-$nbrOne) + 1 : $nbrOne
        $nbrTwoPos = $nbrTwo -lt 0 ? [uint]::MaxValue - (-$nbrTwo) + 1 : $nbrTwo

        $uintMaxVal = [uint]::MaxValue

        $longAdditionResult = ($nbrOnePos + $nbrTwoPos)
        $remainder = $longAdditionResult % $uintMaxVal
        $totalLoops = ($longAdditionResult - $remainder) / $uintMaxVal
        $result = [System.Math]::Abs($remainder - $totalLoops)

        return $result
    }
    #endregion

    $uniquestring = GenerateUniqueString -InputString $InputStringValue
    return $uniqueString
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is not documented anywhere, but its deterministic, meaning you always get the same output if you give the same input, so nothing to worry about.

In case you need to identify the resource afterwards you can come up with a bunch of workaround, you can always get the output of the deployment using `Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` or you can tag the resource with something specific what you can infer dynamically or you could filter the resource out using things like time of creation and other indirect factors

Comment: I'm aware that `uniquestring` is deterministic within ARM templates, my problem is that it is not _available_ from Powershell scripts.

Comment: nothing you can do about that, like i said, just use the same input, shouldnt be too hard

Comment: Use the same input with what? I'm not invoking ARM templates from Powershell, I'm using the AzureRM module which does not include a comparable function. The resource name, which I do need, is a calculated value, but that calculation requires the `uniquestring` function _and that function is not available outside of ARM templates_.

Comment: updated the answer, i thought you are asking the reverse

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/389thoughts/get-uniquestring-generate-unique-id-for-azure-deployments

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh

function Get-UniqueString ([string]$id, $length=13)
{
    $hashArray = (new-object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed).ComputeHash($id.ToCharArray())
        -join ($hashArray[1..$length] | ForEach-Object { [char]($_ % 26 + [byte][char]'a') })
}

Get-UniqueString "foobar"
```

Comment: it seems you reduce a char from 8-bit (or unicode? not sure) to a mod26 variant dropping some value from it. Doesn't that collide too much? I would say we should convert the sha512 hash to base26 the good way; continuously dividing the remaining data by 26.